# Solution of $|x^2-2x|+|x-4|>|x^2-3x+4|$

Tags: inequality

Solve the given inequality

$$|x^2-2x|+|x-4|>|x^2-3x+4|$$

Obviously we can break the modulus sign for different intervals of $x$ and solve but I was wondering if any short cut exists for this particular question because what I see is that inequality is of type:

$$|a|+|b|>|a-b|$$

and we just have to remove points where equality exists.

Comment: I cannot see a shortcut. You have to look separately at the cases $x<0,0<x<2,2<x<4$ and $x>4$. You should find the inequality holds for $0<x<2$ and $x>4$.

Comment: And you can also check any solution here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=f82a944b799eac194ea37a388daa8b19

Comment: @almagest I think @ Mathematics's approach would work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Equality occurs when $ab \leq 0$  i.e. when $a$ and $b$ are of opposite sign.

e.g. for $a=7$ and $b=-3$

Answer (score 0):

By inequality were know that |a|+|b|>= |a-b|. We have to found what values of a,b the equality does holds. If the sign of a and b are opposite then the equality holds . So (x^2-2x) and (x-4) have opposite sign.